# React Native believes that a component is the same as the previous one

Tags: react-native

I have recently started learning React Native and I have a problem which I am not able to understand.

I can't understand why when rendering components stored in an array, using the array index React Native believes that the new component is the same as the old one.

The fact is that I have an array that contains various components, I am passing said array to a component so that depending on the index of the array that I indicate it shows one component or another, my intention was to make a kind of "stepper". This works correctly but the problem is that if for example index 0 of the array contained a "View" component with two "TextInput", and I tell the "stepper" component to display the content of index 1 which also contains an element "View" with two "TextInput", this shows them correctly but if you had the second "InputText" as focus when changing the index to 1 the second "TextInput" appears focused. What owes this?

Thank you very much in advance.

**Stepper Component:**

```
enum STEPPER_ACTIONS {
  SET_NEXT_STEP = 'SET_NEXT_STEP'
}

const Stepper = (
  { steps = [] },
  ref: React.Ref<unknown>
): JSX.Element => {

const [stepper, updateStepper] = useReducer(
    (state, action) => {

      const newStepper = { ...state };

      switch (action.type) {

        case STEPPER_ACTIONS.SET_NEXT_STEP:
          if (newStepper?.activeStep < steps.length) {
            newStepper.visitedSteps.push(newStepper.activeStep);
            newStepper.activeStep += 1;
          }

          return {
            ...newStepper,
          };
      }
    },

    {
      visitedSteps: [],
      activeStep: 0,
    }

  );

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({

    nextStep: () => updateStepper({ type: STEPPER_ACTIONS.SET_NEXT_STEP }),
    
  }));
  
  return (
    <View>
      {steps[stepper?.activeStep]?.content}
    </View>
  );
};

export default forwardRef(Stepper);
```

**SignUpScreen:**

```
function SignUpScreen({ navigation, route }: any): JSX.Element {
  const stepperRef = useRef(null);

  const [user, updateUser] = useReducer(
    (state, action) => {
      const newState = { ...state };
      switch (action.type) {
        case SIGN_UP_ACTIONS.SET_SURNAME:
          return {
            ...newState,
            surname: action?.payload,
          };
        case SIGN_UP_ACTIONS.SET_PHONE:
          return {
            ...newState,
            phone: action.payload,
          };
        case SIGN_UP_ACTIONS.SET_NAME:
          return {
            ...newState,
            name: action?.payload,
          };
        case SIGN_UP_ACTIONS.SET_PASSWORD:
          return {
            ...newState,
            password: action.payload,
          };
     
      }
      return newState;
    },
    {
      phone: '',
      password: '',
      name: '',
      surname: '',
     
    }
  );
  


    const steps = [
        {
          content: FirstStep(updateUser, user)
        },
        {
          content: SecondStep(updateUser, user)
        }
    ];

  return (
    <View>
      <Stepper
        ref={stepperRef}
        steps={steps}
      />

      <Pressable
        onPress={() => stepperRef?.current?.nextStep()}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default SignUpScreen;
```

**FirstStep:**

```
function FirstStep(
  updateUser,
  user
): JSX.Element {

  return (
    <View>

      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(value)=>updateUser({
            type: SIGN_UP_ACTIONS.SET_NAME,
            payload: value,
        })}
        value={user?.name}
        placeholder="Name"
      />
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(value)=>updateUser({
            type: SIGN_UP_ACTIONS.SET_SURNAME,
            payload: value,
        })}
        value={user?.surname}
        placeholder="Surname"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
export default FirstStep;
```

**SecondStep:**

```
function SecondStep(
  updateUser,
  user
): JSX.Element {

  return (
    <View>

      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(value)=>updateUser({
            type: SIGN_UP_ACTIONS.SET_PASSWORD,
            payload: value,
        })}
        value={user?.password}
        placeholder="Password"
      />
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(value)=>updateUser({
            type: SIGN_UP_ACTIONS.SET_PHONE,
            payload: value,
        })}
        value={user?.phone}
        placeholder="Phone"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
export default SecondStep;
```

**SignUpActions:**

```
export enum SIGN_UP_ACTIONS {
  SET_NAME = 'SET_NAME',
  SET_SURNAME = 'SET_SURNAME',
  SET_PHONE = 'SET_PHONE',
  SET_PASSWORD = 'SET_PASSWORD',
}
```

EDIT: Added my code.

Comment: Waiting for your code to help you :)

Comment: Provide the code or a minimal example please.

Comment: @devpolo I add my code

Comment: @ZhivkoNikolov I add my code

Comment: First of all, I believe that the entire `useReducer` logic should be higher in the tree to make it work. Like in `SignUpScreen`